# MapReduce on Cassandra execution error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I am running a sample mapreduce program(wordcount) to query cassandra data. 
I have included cassandra jar files to hadoop class path "export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/share/cassandra/lib/*:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" as specified in http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport: on each task tracker. But when I am building jar file I get errors as shown below.[image: Output from command line]
.
.
.
.
.
.

[image: Error output].

How to build jar file such that it can run on cassandra data?

How to give path of cassandra data to mapreduce program? In general, for HDFS data processing we give command like "hadoop jar filename.jar ConfigClassName inputfile outputfile". In case of cassandra how to give same command?

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please, try building like this --

```
javac -classpath $HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar WordCount.java
```

I suppose, when building you also need to put the HADOOP_CLASSPATH in the javac classpath.

Comment: Thanks. I got jar file, but how to execute this on cassandra data?

Comment: No clue! Haven't really used Cassandra. Just replied to help you compile the jar. May be you can see the guides :)